# why this shows runtime error in ideone & visual studio but not in code blocks?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dynamic, reference, runtime-error

Why the following code showing runtime error in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Ql6fRC) & also in visual studio but not in Code Blocks?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass{
int *p;
public:
myclass(int i)
{p=new int;
 *p=i;}
~myclass(){delete p;}
int *get(){return p;}
};

void show (myclass x){
int *i=x.get();
cout<<*i<<endl;
}

int main() {
myclass a(19);
show (a);
return 0;
}
```

And I also dont know what is wrong with this code either (runtime error in both ideone and visual studio but not in code blocks)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int *i=new int ;
int j=19;
i=&j;
cout<<*i<<endl;
delete i;
return 0;
}
```

I have a hunch in the first case memory of **p** is deleted once in **show()** function and then again after **main()** so deleting same memory may cause this runtime error (I m not sure though, whether it is the case or not,pls explain why) and using a reference in void show (myclass **&x**) did eliminate the error but i fail to see what changed,and in 2nd case i think the error is using the address of j,if assigned the value of j the error will be gone, but in **both** these cases code blocks didnot show me any error, so if anyone can pls clarify this compiler behaviour it will be very appreciable (sry for posting such a long question). Thnks in advance.

Comment: You want to say that in both cases when running it in Code::Blocks code runs to completion? Can't believe in that, as IDE has nothing to do with this.

Comment: hmm, codeblocks compiled it, and threw no error, not even run time error while showing the result to console, and exited normally upon pressing any key @SChepurin

Comment: Then, *undefined behavior* is a fundamental property of your version of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class manages dynamically allocated resources, but does not follow [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). Your call to `show` involves a copy of a `myclass` object. This results in two objects "managing" the same memory. One of these is destroyed upon leaving `show()`, its resources are de-allocated via the call to `delete` in the destructor. That leaves the object in `main()` holding a pointer to de-allocated memory, which it then tries to call `delete` on.

This is  *undefined behaviour*. It means that the program *may* exhibit some obvious error, but it may also run and exit silently.

The bottom line is, *if* your class needs to manage resources (and that is an important *if*), then follow the rule of three (or five in C++11).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is a typical case of "undefined behaviour". And yes, in your `myclass` example, `p` is deleted twice, which is what causes problems. In the second case, you are simply deleting a pointer that was not allocated with `new`, which means you are not following the rules as you should.

Undefined behaviour is where the C and C++ (and other languages) explain what happens by saying "it's undefined". The specification does this to avoid having to exclude or make expensive workarounds in hardware that has/hasn't got a specific behaviour - for example, if the C++ standard said that "The C++ runtime must detect `delete` of memory that hasn't been allocated with `new`", it would be very hard to write a `delete` that does the right thing (you may think that it's not too difficult, and for a given architecture, it may not be, but in a 16-bit microcontroller, it may add significant overhead. As one of the basic principles of C or C++ is "you don't pay for things you didn't ask for", this sort of overhead would be unacceptable. [Never mind that such a scheme couldn't be made 100% secure anyway, since it's always possible that the pointer could be "fake" and still match all the checks that were made in some way or another].

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the copy constructor.

```
void show (myclass x){ 
int *i=x.get(); // here x.p points to same location as a.p
cout<<*i<<endl;
}
//here x.p is deleted in the destructor for x and so is a.p.
```

As already mentioned it is advised to follow the rule of three if dynamic memory allocation is involved.